# Ubuntu Server VLAN config

Tags: networking, server

I would like to do the following (using either MAC address or FreeRaduis Login):

I have PC1 and PC2 belonging to Owner A and PC3 and PC4 belonging to Owner B. They are all connected to the same WiFi network.

All Owner A's PCs must act like they are connected to the same LAN, but not have any access to any of Owner B's PCs, and visa versa. They all must have internet access.

How can I configure such a setup on Ubuntu Server? And would I have to have two NICs (One connected to the WAN and the other to the LAN). Is there any specific switches needed?

I have tried to look for the answer myself, but all I can find is using static IPs. I cannot fix any of the users' IPs.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you uses two different `SSID` for each owner.  Then you can set up good enough security of their `WLAN` (`WiFi`).  Give each `SSID` an own network, like Owner A `192.168.10.0/24` and Owner B `192.168.20.0/24`.

After that, you can set up the router to route between them and controll access with a firewall between the two networks.  Basicly exchange the `VLAN` with the `SSID`.  If you want to use wired network, you set up a switch in the router and bridge the `SSID` with the right switch.

I do belive that there can be problems with `VLAN` over `WLAN`.  But my memory could be wrong there.

Comment: Will this work with a radius server? My example contains 2 owners but it will be used for 50+ and I want to regulate it with a radius server.

Comment: Oh, that was not mentioned in the question.  I have no experiance with radious server login.  But it is designed for Enterprice situations, so why wouldn't it?  The network part will work, the login I don't know.